# Content sources for content types

Tags: search, crawl, content-source

Is it possible to have content sources for specific content types?

Use case: we have a lot of announcement lists in various site collections. We want to aggregate announcement items with certain categories using a search result webpart. The default crawl interval is about an hour for those site collections, we'd want to decrease this interval for announcements only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, content sources are defined by start addresses and crawl rules. You could try to define a targeted crawl rule, but that would exclude the other content and you cannot reuse the start address.

What I would suggest is that you architect your farm so that your search topology can use Continuous Crawl. This brings your index freshness to near 15 minutes (or less). Then define Result Sources for your Content Types.